# How to pass multiple parameters to rmiregistry

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

I run rmiregistry from my code using ProcessBuilder. How do I pass more than one argument to the rmiregistry process?

Till now I used `-J_xmx1024m`. I know need to pass in an aditional parameter (-D).

Should I do something like this:

```
-J-Xmx1024m -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
```

or like this:

```
-J-Xmx1024m -J-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=tru
```

Comment: What happens when you try the two options you have posted?

Comment: Why do you need to increase the heap? It's only a hash table basically. And why do you need to set useCodebaseOnly?

Answer (score 1):

`-J-Xmx1024m -J-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true`

That is the one to use.